# Is there any way to modify the pydevd_file_utils.PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON value without having to modify that file?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using the pydev plugin to debug a remote application.

This (remote) application has a structure of files that differs from the structure where my Eclipse is running. This leads to problems when I set the breakpoints from the Eclipse IDE because the pydev debugger server cannot match the absolute path of the file with the file on the remote application and hence the breakpoint isn´t hit.

I dont want to hardcode the pydevd_file_utils.PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON constant to enable filepath translations.

Do you know some way to modify this value without changing the file?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/issues/184

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 ways of setting the path translation:

1. Use an environment variable such as `PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON` that maps the paths from the client to the server side.

The value is a json string with a `list(list(str, str))` such that:

`PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON=[["c:/local/path", "/path/in/server"]]`

Note that you may set the environment variable in any place you'd like (such as the `Environment` tab in the `Python interpreter` preferences page, in the OS itself, in the launch config, etc).

2. Use the `pydevd` API to set the tracing at runtime from the python process:

```python
from pydevd_file_utils import setup_client_server_paths

MY_PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON = [
    ('/home/user/local-project', '/remote/path/to/project'),
]
setup_client_server_paths(MY_PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON)

# At this point we could connect to the remote debugger client with:
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace("10.0.0.12")
```

See: https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html for more info on the Remote Debugging.

**Note**: the mapping set in `Window > Preferences` select `PyDev > Debug > Source Locator` doesn't really map to that environment variable nor the actual debugger mapping (that's a separate translation that only translates paths which are found on Eclipse locally and it's not really passed on to the debugger to hit breakpoints remotely).

Comment: at 2018, with latest pydev and eclipse, I used all the answers, none of them works, no matter how I try it, when I set breakpoint from my windows eclipse, the remote Linux terminal always shows: pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist, then it add the current directory + where the file is based in my Windows pc. so it ends as "/root/project\C:eclipseproject\project", at moment I run out options..

Comment: <!-- language: lang-python -->

    import os
    os.environ['PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON'] = r'[["C:\\Users\\WindowsКириллица\\src", "/home/frost-nzcr4/dst"]]'

    print('Before settrace')
    import pydevd: pydevd.settrace('192.168.1.116', port=5678)
    print('After settrace')  # Automatically stops here.


    def main():
        a = 5  # Set breakpoint here and it stops.
        return a + 5

    print(main())

This code works on:

* Host: Debian, Python 3.5, pydevd 1.3.0
* Guest: Windows 7 (on VirtualBox), Python 3.6, Eclipse 4.7.3a, Pydev 6.4.1

Comment: after having the same issues as Junchen, the code in frost's comment works!
import os
os.environ['PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON'] = r'[["C:\\Users\\Ryan\\Documents\\4V_Projects\\4V_Firmware\\TestCode\\src", "/home/pi/src"]]'
print('Before settrace')
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('10.0.0.7', port=5678)
print('After settrace') # Automatically stops here.
def main():
    a = 5 # Set breakpoint here and it stops.
    return a + 5

print(main())

Comment: could please be more clear in the description where things should be configured and what the direction of the mapping is. Also an example with a real configuration e.g. linux/MacOS or Windows/Linux or something would be really helpful. Currently I can only guess these aspects.

Comment: Thanks Fabio Zadrozny, he consolidate answers of Emilio M. and my own and spreads the light on Eclipse behavior.

Comment: The current behavior is IMHO awkward and badly needs improvement. The remote debugging path mapping should be configurable fully remotely and need no settings on the local machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by setting a new environment variable like this:

```
PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON='[["client_src_fullpath", "remote_src_fullpath"]]'
```

In linux simply run that before starting the program from the command line, or set is as a global variable.

In windows you will need to set it as a global system variable.

> Variable name: PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON
>
> Variable value: [["client_src_path", "remote_src_path"]]

As an alternative, you can also do this in code, BUT you need to do it BEFORE you import pydevd:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON",'[["client_src_path","remote_src_path"]]')
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace("10.0.2.2", port=5678,stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True, suspend=False,patch_multiprocessing=True)
```

(I'm aware this is a very old question, but none of the answers were updated to the current code)

Comment: thx for this - it sometimes works but has some reliability issues. What to dht suspend= and patch_multiprocessing options mean and where are those documented?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no good way to do that. 
As a workaround I explicitly replaced function NormFileToServer by adding the following code at the beginning of my source file.

```
def SrcPathMapping(file):
  eclipse_src_path = 'C:\\tmp\\workspace\\test\\Scripts\\'
  server_src_path  = '/home/tester/test/Scripts/'
  return file.replace(eclipse_src_path, server_src_path)

import pysrc.pydevd as pydevd  
pydevd.NormFileToServer = SrcPathMapping
```

This simplistic mapping is sufficient when all source files are located in one directory. For proper implementation of the mapping function check NormFileToServer in the pydevd_file_utils.

Comment: That's to complicated and outdated